# Changing the icon of a button when it is clicked and the activity doing something when focus of the button is lost

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-button

I want to make a button in my android app such that when I put my finger on the button (the butten gets focused) at that moment the icon of the button should change (via button.setBackgroundDrawable or something like that) and when the button loses focus (I lift my finger off of it) then it does what it is supposed to do and the icon stays changed (go to another activity, check smth, input smth, etc. whatever). I have no idea which functions say when it is given focus and when it loses it. Any ideas?

Comment: can we get your code.!?

Comment: use `onTouchListener`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a button_state.xml file in drawable

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/onfocusonstatepressed" />
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/onstatepressed" />
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/onfocus"/>
<item android:state_focused="false" android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
</selector>
```

Next in your main layout xml add an attribute to your button

```
android:background="@drawable/button_state"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't get a Focus when in touch-mode. As soon as you touch a button, it's in pressed mode. Focus is only there for devices having hardware buttons (or a mouse) allowing to select a View and then 'press' it.

Answer (score 0):

Register a TouchListener to Button:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new ButtonDownListener());
```

Here your Listener

```
public class ButtonDownListener implements OnTouchListener{

           public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
            if(event == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                //do your stuff
            }
            else if(event == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                //do your stuff
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd recommend using the standard View.OnTouchListener instead of implementing it if you're not going to add functionallity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onTouchListener like this

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

        //This triggers when you lift your finger
    } else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

       //this triggers when you put your finger down
    }
    return false;
}
```

});